# Extending the list of static autocompletion commands with dynamic values

Tags: haskell, autocomplete

I have following program in Haskell that takes input from command line and modifies state of `mydata` variable:

```
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances, MultiParamTypeClasses, UndecidableInstances #-}

import Text.Regex.PCRE
import System.Console.Haskeline
import System.IO
import System.IO.Unsafe
import Control.Monad.State.Strict
import qualified Data.ByteString.Char8 as B
import Data.Maybe
import Data.List 
import qualified Data.Map as M

data MyDataState = MyDataState {
  mydata :: [Int],
  showEven :: Bool
} deriving (Show)

myfile :: FilePath
myfile = "data.txt"

defaultFlagValue :: Bool
defaultFlagValue = False

saveDataToFile :: [Int] -> IO ()
saveDataToFile _data = withFile myfile WriteMode $ \h -> hPutStr h (unwords $ map show _data)

{-# NOINLINE loadDataFromFile #-} 
loadDataFromFile :: [Int]
loadDataFromFile = map read . words $ B.unpack $ unsafePerformIO $ B.readFile myfile

wordList = [":help", ":q", ":commands", ":show", ":save", ":edit", ":new", ":toggleShowEven"]

searchFunc :: String -> [Completion]
searchFunc str = map simpleCompletion $ filter (str `isPrefixOf`) (wordList)

mySettings :: Settings (StateT MyDataState IO)
mySettings = Settings { historyFile = Just "myhist"
                      , complete = completeWord Nothing " \t" $ return . searchFunc
                      , autoAddHistory = True
                      }

help :: InputT (StateT MyDataState IO) ()
help = liftIO $ mapM_ putStrLn
       [ ""
       , ":help     - this help"
       , ":q        - quit"
       , ":commands - list available commands"
       , ""
       ]

commands :: InputT (StateT MyDataState IO) ()
commands = liftIO $ mapM_ putStrLn
       [ ""
       , ":show           - display data"
       , ":save           - save results to file"
       , ":edit           - edit data"
       , ":new            - generate new element "
       , ":toggleShowEven - toggle display of even elements"
       , ""
       ]

toggleFlag :: InputT (StateT MyDataState IO) ()
toggleFlag = do
  MyDataState mydata flag <- get
  put $ MyDataState mydata (not flag)

instance MonadState s m => MonadState s (InputT m) where
    get = lift get
    put = lift . put
    state = lift . state

parseInput :: String -> InputT (StateT MyDataState IO) () 
parseInput inp
  | inp =~ "^\\:q"        = return ()

  | inp =~ "^\\:he"       = help >> mainLoop

  | inp =~ "^\\:commands" = commands >> mainLoop

  | inp =~ "^\\:toggleShowEven" = toggleFlag >> mainLoop

  | inp =~ "^\\:show" = do
      MyDataState mydata showEven <- get
      liftIO $ putStrLn $ unwords $ if showEven 
        then map show mydata
        else map show $ filter odd mydata
      mainLoop 

  | inp =~ "^\\:save" = do
      MyDataState mydata _ <- get 
      liftIO $ saveDataToFile mydata
      mainLoop

  | inp =~ "^\\:load" = do
      put (MyDataState loadDataFromFile defaultFlagValue)
      mainLoop

  | inp =~ "^\\:new" = do
      MyDataState mydata showEven <- get                     -- reads the state
      inputData <- getInputLine "\tEnter data: "
      case inputData of 
        Nothing -> put ( MyDataState [0] showEven )
        Just inputD -> 
          put $ if null mydata 
            then MyDataState [read inputD] showEven
            else MyDataState (mydata ++ [read inputD]) showEven -- updates the state
      mainLoop

  | inp =~ ":" = do
    outputStrLn $ "\nNo command \"" ++ inp ++ "\"\n"
    mainLoop

  | otherwise = handleInput inp

handleInput :: String -> InputT (StateT MyDataState IO) ()
handleInput inp = mainLoop

mainLoop :: InputT (StateT MyDataState IO ) ()
mainLoop = do
  inp <- getInputLine "% "
  maybe (return ()) parseInput inp

greet :: IO ()
greet = mapM_ putStrLn
        [ ""
        , "          MyProgram"
        , "=============================="
        , "For help type \":help\""
        , ""
        ]

main :: IO ((), MyDataState)
main = do 
    greet 
    runStateT (runInputT mySettings mainLoop) MyDataState {mydata = [] , showEven = defaultFlagValue}
```

Example of interaction with the program above:

```
*Main> main

          MyProgram
==============================
For help type ":help"

% :commands 

:show           - display data
:save           - save results to file
:edit           - edit data
:new            - generate new element 
:toggleShowEven - toggle display of even elements

% :show

% :new
    Enter data: 1
% :new 
    Enter data: 2
% :new 
    Enter data: 3
% :show
1 3
% :toggleShowEven 
% :show
1 2 3
%
```

As you might have noticed, this program is using command line autocompletion for typical commands such as `:show`, `:edit`, `:new`, etc.

My question is following. Is it possible to extend the list of commands available for autocompletion (`wordsList` variable) with the values from `MyDataState`? For example, if `mydata` contains values `1, 2, 3`, I want it to be shown together with commands available for autocompletion - when typing <kbd>:</kbd><kbd>Tab</kbd>, I would get the following list of commands instead of just statically defined via `wordsList`: **`:help`**, **`:q`**, **`:commands`**, **`:show`**, **`:save`**, **`:edit`**, **`:new`**, **`:toggleShowEven`**, **`:1`**, **`:2`**, **`:3`**. How do I need to extend `searchFunc` definition to include values defined in `MyDataState`? Is it possible at all?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the `Settings` record, the field `complete` has type `CompletionFunc (StateT MyDataState IO)`, implying that we have access to the state for autocompletion.

Currently the definition of `mySettings` uses

```
complete = completeWord Nothing " \t" $ return . searchFunc
```

This `return` wraps a pure function, which thus ignores the stateful context. We can replace that with a computation accessing the state:

```
complete = completeWord Nothing " \t" $ \str -> do
  _data <- get
  return (searchFunc _data str)
```

also changing the type of `searchFunc` for example to:

```
searchFunc :: MyDataState -> String -> [Completion]
```

Comment: If I replace `return . searchFunc` with `return . (\str -> do _data <- get; searchFunc _data str)`, I get `No instance for (MonadState MyDataState [])
      arising from a use of ‘get’
    In a stmt of a 'do' block: _data <- get` and don't know how to fix it.

Comment: Remove the leading `return .`. I amended my post to show what the code should look like.

Comment: The error I get if I do as you described is following: `Couldn't match type ‘[]’ with ‘StateT MyDataState IO’
    Expected type: CompletionFunc (StateT MyDataState IO)
      Actual type: CompletionFunc []
    In the ‘complete’ field of a record;

Couldn't match type ‘Completion’ with ‘[Completion]’
    Expected type: [[Completion]]
      Actual type: [Completion]
    In a stmt of a 'do' block: searchFunc _data str`

Comment: Here is my code in online IDE that you can tweak and run: https://ideone.com/Zr4pK1

Comment: Oh sorry, `completeWord` expects an argument of type `(String -> m [Completion])`, so the result of `searchFunc` needs to be `return`-ed: `return (searchFunc _data str)`.

Comment: I have a similar question in a separate thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49823709/command-line-autocompletion-based-on-context maybe you could help on that too, I would be grateful if you could take a look.