# Command line autocompletion based on context

Tags: haskell, autocomplete

I have a following program (and here is the [link to the program in an online IDE](https://ideone.com/sFcL2N)), purpose of which is to explore Haskell command line autocompletion capabilities:

```
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances, MultiParamTypeClasses, UndecidableInstances #-}

import System.Console.Haskeline
import System.IO
import System.IO.Unsafe
import Control.Monad.State.Strict
import qualified Data.ByteString.Char8 as B
import Data.Maybe
import Data.List 
import qualified Data.Map as M

data MyDataState = MyDataState {
  mydata :: [Int],
  selectedElement :: Int,
  showEven :: Bool
} deriving (Show)

instance MonadState s m => MonadState s (InputT m) where
    get = lift get
    put = lift . put
    state = lift . state

myfile :: FilePath
myfile = "data.txt"

defaultFlagValue :: Bool
defaultFlagValue = False

defaultSelectedElement :: Int
defaultSelectedElement = 0

saveDataToFile :: [Int] -> IO ()
saveDataToFile _data = withFile myfile WriteMode $ \h -> hPutStr h (unwords $ map show _data)

{-# NOINLINE loadDataFromFile #-} 
loadDataFromFile :: [Int]
loadDataFromFile = map read . words $ B.unpack $ unsafePerformIO $ B.readFile myfile

generalSetOfCommands = M.fromList [
    (":help", "outputs this help"), 
    (":q", "quits the program"), 
    (":commands", "list of all commands applicable to the current selection"), 
    (":show", "show current set of data"), 
    (":save", "saves data to file"), 
    (":load", "loads data from file"), 
    (":select", "selects one of the data set elements to be current"), 
    (":new", "adds element to the data set"), 
    (":toggleShowEven", "toggles the flag that controls output of even data set elements")
  ]
firstSetOfCommands = M.fromList [
    (":command1_1", "description of :command1_1"), 
    (":command1_2", "description of :command1_2"), 
    (":command1_3", "description of :command1_3"), 
    (":command1_4", "description of :command1_4")
  ]
secondSetOfCommands = M.fromList [
    (":command2_1", "description of :command2_1"), 
    (":command2_2", "description of :command2_2"), 
    (":command2_3", "description of :command2_3"), 
    (":command2_4", "description of :command2_4")
  ]
thirdSetOfCommands = M.fromList [
    (":command3_1", "description of :command3_1"), 
    (":command3_2", "description of :command3_2"), 
    (":command3_3", "description of :command3_3"), 
    (":command3_4", "description of :command3_4")
  ]

searchFunc :: MyDataState -> String -> [Completion]
searchFunc (MyDataState mydata selectedElement showEven) str = 
    map simpleCompletion $ filter (str `isPrefixOf`) (M.keys generalSetOfCommands ++ 
        case selectedElement of 
          1 -> M.keys firstSetOfCommands
          2 -> M.keys secondSetOfCommands
          3 -> M.keys thirdSetOfCommands
          otherwise -> []
    )

mySettings :: Settings (StateT MyDataState IO)
mySettings = Settings { historyFile = Just "myhist"
                      , complete = completeWord Nothing " \t" $ \str -> do 
                          _data <- get
                          return $ searchFunc _data str 
                      , autoAddHistory = True
                      }

help :: InputT (StateT MyDataState IO) ()
help = commands

commands :: InputT (StateT MyDataState IO) ()
commands = do
        (MyDataState mydata selectedElement flag) <- get
        liftIO $ mapM_ putStrLn $ case selectedElement of 
          1 -> M.elems $ M.mapWithKey (\k v -> k ++ "\t - " ++ v) $ M.unionWith (++) generalSetOfCommands firstSetOfCommands
          2 -> M.elems $ M.mapWithKey (\k v -> k ++ "\t - " ++ v) $ M.unionWith (++) generalSetOfCommands secondSetOfCommands
          3 -> M.elems $ M.mapWithKey (\k v -> k ++ "\t - " ++ v) $ M.unionWith (++) generalSetOfCommands thirdSetOfCommands
          otherwise -> M.elems $ M.mapWithKey (\k v -> k ++ "\t - " ++ v) generalSetOfCommands

toggleFlag :: InputT (StateT MyDataState IO) ()
toggleFlag = do
  MyDataState mydata selectedElement flag <- get
  put $ MyDataState mydata selectedElement (not flag)

parseInput :: String -> InputT (StateT MyDataState IO) () 
parseInput inp
  | ":q" == inp = return ()

  | ":help" == inp = help >> mainLoop

  | ":commands" == inp = (commands >> mainLoop)

  | ":toggleShowEven" == inp = do 
      toggleFlag 
      MyDataState mydata selectedElement flag <- get
      liftIO $ putStrLn $ "Flag has been set to " ++ (show flag)
      mainLoop

  | ":select" == inp = do
      MyDataState mydata selectedElement showEven <- get
      inputData <- getInputLine "\tSelect one of the data elements to be current: "
      case inputData of
        Nothing -> put (MyDataState mydata selectedElement showEven)
        Just inputD ->
          let inputInt = read inputD 
          in if elem inputInt mydata
            then put (MyDataState mydata inputInt showEven)
            else do 
              liftIO $ putStrLn $ "The element you entered (" ++ (show inputInt) ++ ") has not been found in the data set"
              put (MyDataState mydata selectedElement showEven)
      mainLoop  

  | ":show" == inp = do
      MyDataState mydata selectedElement showEven <- get
      liftIO $ putStrLn $ unwords $ if showEven 
        then map (\x -> if x == selectedElement then "[" ++ show x ++ "]" else show x) mydata
        else map (\x -> if x == selectedElement then "[" ++ show x ++ "]" else show x) $ filter odd mydata
      mainLoop 

  | ":save" == inp = do
      MyDataState mydata selectedElement _ <- get 
      liftIO $ saveDataToFile mydata
      mainLoop

  | ":load" == inp = do
      put (MyDataState loadDataFromFile defaultSelectedElement defaultFlagValue)
      mainLoop

  | ":new" == inp = do
      MyDataState mydata selectedElement showEven <- get                     -- reads the state
      inputData <- getInputLine "\tEnter data: "
      case inputData of 
        Nothing -> 
          put $ if null mydata
            then ( MyDataState [0] selectedElement showEven )
            else ( MyDataState mydata selectedElement showEven )
        Just inputD -> 
          put $ if null mydata 
            then MyDataState [read inputD] selectedElement showEven
            else MyDataState (mydata ++ [read inputD]) selectedElement showEven -- updates the state
      mainLoop

  | ":" == inp = do
    outputStrLn $ "\nNo command \"" ++ inp ++ "\"\n"
    mainLoop

  | otherwise = handleInput inp

handleInput :: String -> InputT (StateT MyDataState IO) ()
handleInput inp = mainLoop

mainLoop :: InputT (StateT MyDataState IO ) ()
mainLoop = do
  inp <- getInputLine "% "
  maybe (return ()) parseInput inp

greet :: IO ()
greet = mapM_ putStrLn
        [ ""
        , "          MyProgram"
        , "=============================="
        , "For help type \":help\""
        , ""
        ]

main :: IO ((), MyDataState)
main = do 
    greet 
    runStateT (runInputT mySettings mainLoop) MyDataState {mydata = [] , selectedElement = defaultSelectedElement, showEven = defaultFlagValue}
```

In my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49617675/extending-the-list-of-static-autocompletion-commands-with-dynamic-values) I was struggling with adding possibility to take into account program state and form autocompletion list based on that. Now that I have overcome this problem, another question arises - how could I take into account current context of the command line command?

For instance, here is a short example of interaction with my program:

```
*Main> main

          MyProgram
==============================
For help type ":help"

% :show

% :new
    Enter data: 1
% :new
    Enter data: 2
% :new
    Enter data: 3
% :select
    Select one of the data elements to be current: 2
% :show
1 3
% :toggleShowEven
Flag has been set to True
% :show
1 [2] 3
% :
:commands        :load            :q               :select          :toggleShowEven  :command2_2      :command2_4
:help            :new             :save            :show            :command2_1      :command2_3
%
```

As you can see, it autocompletes list of currently available commands based on current selection (in this example it is value `2`). But what if I want to generate new set of commands for existing command, `:select` for example?

In this case, on input

```
% :select
    Select one of the data elements to be current:
```

when pressing <kbd>Tab</kbd>, I want to get list of available values for autocompletion **`1 2 3`** and only those values. Is it possible to somehow take into account the place where I am calling autocompletion function?

What I expect it to be is different versions of `searchFunc` function for different context. For example, for `:select` command it would be `selectSearchFunc`. But I don't know how could I make it be applied only when `:select` command is called. It seems that `mySettings` somehow should be redefined to be applied not on global scope, but on local scope, but it is not really obvious how to do that. I would appreciate any suggestion that would help to resolve this issue.

Comment: I'd recommend using [`haskeline`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/haskeline) for this. If you really want to do it by hand, [ANSI escape sequences](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code#CSI_sequences) are what you're looking for, but good luck.

Comment: @AJFarmar Isn't that already using *haskeline*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can extend the state so that `searchFunc` can behave differently inside a select.

```
data WholeState = WholeState MyDataState MyCmdlineState

data MyCmdlineState = TopLevel | Select   -- etc.

searchFunc (WholeState mydatastate TopLevel) str = (...)  -- what the current searchFunc does
searchFunc (WholeState mydatastate Select  ) str = (...)  -- special completion in a select
```

Then use a "bracket function" to set the command-line state in a fixed scope.

```
localCmdlineState :: MonadState WholeState m => MyCmdlineState -> m a -> m a
localCmdlineState mcstate run = do
  WholeState mydatastate s0 <- get
  put (WholeState mydatastate mcstate)
  run
  WholeState mydatastate' _ <- get
  put (WholeState mydatastate' s0)
```

This can be used in `parseInput`, in the `":select"` case, the `getInputLine` becomes

```
inputData <- localCmdlineState Select $ getInputLine "\tSelect one of the data elements to be current: "
```

---

Arguably, `localCmdlineState` is a bit complex. You have to pay attention to where each bit of the state goes. Another issue is that the `MyCmdlineState` introduces some indirection that makes the code a bit hard to follow.

One way to alleviate this is to use lenses, so only the relevant parts of `WholeState` appear in the code when we access them.

An even better approach is to use a different abstraction than `MonadState` to carry the current state of command-line completion (`MyCmdlineState`). In particular, I'm thinking of `MonadReader`, whose `local` function is exactly what we need.

Instead of a new enumeration type, why not just carry the `searchFunc` itself:

```
type SearchFunc = MyDataState -> String -> [Completion]
```

And instead of pattern-matching, we just make more definitions. It's also possible to create and pass `SearchFunc` on the fly.

```
topLevelSearchFunc :: SearchFunc
selectSearchFunc :: SearchFunc
```

We make the stack a bit longer:

```
type M = ReaderT SearchFunc (StateT MyDataState IO)
```

Implementing `MonadReader` for `InputT` is a bit tricky. `lift`-ing is not sufficient. Hopefully there is `mapInputT`.

```
instance MonadReader s m => MonadReader s (InputT m) where
    reader = lift . reader
    local f = mapInputT (local f)
```

Another bit that needs to change is `mySettings`, which thus gets `searchFunc` from its environment instead of a constant.

```
mySettings :: Settings M
mySettings = Settings { historyFile = Just "myhist"
                      , complete = completeWord Nothing " \t" $ \str -> do 
                          _data <- get
                          searchFunc <- ask
                          return $ searchFunc _data str 
                      , autoAddHistory = True
                      }
```

In `main`, we start with `topLevelSearchFunc`

```
main = do
    greet
    runStateT (runReaderT (runInputT mySettings mainLoop) topLevelSearchFunc) MyDataState {mydata = [] , selectedElement = defaultSelectedElement, showEven = defaultFlagValue}
```

In `parseInput`, we set the `SearchFunc` locally, with syntax very similar to my previous solution:

```
inputData <- local (\_ -> selectSearchFunc) $ getInputLine "\tSelect one of the data elements to be current: "
```

---

[Full gist](https://gist.github.com/Lysxia/2e834c48f05b6040576b058694132528)

---

The advantage of this is that making `SearchFunc` only available via a `MonadReader` effect makes it clear that it can only be modified locally (using `local`).

The hope is that thus compartmentalizing the various components of the application state prevents them from interfering with each other and reduces the potential for mistakes.